# Check something synchronous before every Backbone HTTP request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js, marionette

In every authenticated requests (GET, POST, etc) of my Backbone/Marionette application I must to attach an accessToken.

I store this accessToken and expireDate in the localStorage.

To check if the accessToken is expired I call this method: user.checkToken(). 
If is expired, the method renew the accessToken with a POST request to my backend.

Where should I put this check? I mean, in which part of the application?

Should I rewrite my on **Backbone.sync** method or use **ajax.setup** "beforeSend" ?

Thanks in advance for your advices/idea.

Comment: would $.ajaxPreFilter work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backbone uses jQuery (see the note for a solution that may work with Zepto) for ajax requests, so you can use (as suggested by Edward) [jQuery.ajaxPrefilter](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxPrefilter/).

I did a little test for this task, let me know if there's any problem:

```
function tokenIsExpired() {
    return true;
}

function createPromiseFunction(method, jqXHRsource, jqXHR) {
    return function() {
        jqXHRsource[method] = function(f) {
            if (f) {
                jqXHR[method] = function() {
                    f.apply(this, arguments);
                };
            }

            return this;
        };
    }
}

function updateToken() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: '',
        method: 'GET',
        data: {some:'data', here:'yes'},
        success: function() {
            // update the token sir
            console.log('token call done')
        },
        skipTokenCheck: true // required
    });
}


$.ajaxPrefilter(function( options, originalOptions, jqXHR ) {
    /*
     * check if token is expired every time a new ajax request is made
     * if it is expired, aborts the current requests, updated the token
     * and eventually does the original request again.
     */

    if (!options.skipTokenCheck && tokenIsExpired()) {
        // at this point no callback should have be added to the promise object

        var methodsNames = [
            'done',
            'always',
            'fail',
            'progress',
            'then'
        ];

        var methods = {};

        // copy the callbacks when they're added to the old request

        for (var i = 0; i < methodsNames.length; i++) {
            var name = methodsNames[i];

            createPromiseFunction(name, jqXHR, methods)();
        };

        jqXHR.abort();

        // TODO: error checks
        updateToken().done(function() {
            console.log('done');
            var newReq = $.ajax($.extend(originalOptions, {skipTokenCheck: true}));

            for (var i = 0; i < methodsNames.length; i++) {
                var name = methodsNames[i];
                var f = methods[name];

                if (f) {
                    newReq[name](f);
                }
            };
        });
    }
});

var p = $.get('.');

p.done(function() { console.log(arguments); }).fail(function() {
    console.log('fail');
});
```

Looks like that ajaxPrefilter doesn't work with Zepto. Alternatively you can use the [ajaxBeforeSend](http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/) event.

> Returning false in the beforeSend function will cancel the request.

Should be easy to adapt the code I posted above.

Comment: Zepto does not support ajaxPrefilter.

Comment: @JamesWatkins yes, there is a note in the answer :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that. The first sentence confused me, that's why I commented. I will check out ajaxBeforeSend. Thanks!

Comment: No worries! I'll edit the question to make it clearer :)

Answer (score 2):

Overwrite your model's `sync()` function and do whatever you need to do.. Something like:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  sync: function() {
    // Put your code here

    Backbone.Model.prototype.sync.apply(this, arguments);
  }
});
```

**Edit #1:**

Not sure where you get `user` (as well as other variables) from but here it is:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  sync: function() {
    user.checkToken().done(_.bind(function(){
       Backbone.Model.prototype.sync.apply(this, [ method, model, options ]);
     });
  }, this);
});
```

Comment: Did you mean Backbone.sync so every requests can have this check?
Something like this: dpaste.com/hold/1278286 
I have just tried but I think is not possible, must I use deferred object?

Comment: No. I'll edit the answer's code so you see the exact meaning. In general you should not do it the way you've tried, but you rather should `extend()` backbone's `Model`, like I showed in the answer.

Comment: Thanks Poni, but I want that ALL requests have this check. 
Not only the request made through a Model or a Collection.
Hints?

Comment: yeah, just override that! Override the sync method of the library you are using to handle Ajax requests.